# How to remove query parameter from url in laravel via middleware?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel and I am facing one problem, I have URL like this

> https://example.com?version=2.2.0

Now I am creating middleware after matching the version the query parameter should remove.
Below is the middleware code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $request->replace($request->except(['version']));
        return $next($request);
    }
```

But it is not working to remove query parameters although working post data.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use just `remove` method?

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $request->remove('version');
    return $next($request);
}
```

This is what remove method does under the hood, in laravel source code:

```
/**
 * Removes a parameter.
 */
public function remove(string $key)
{
    unset($this->parameters[$key]);
}
```

Comment: "message": "Method Illuminate\\Http\\Request::remove does not exist."

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: we are using laravel version 6.2

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to remove the `?version=2.2.0` from your url?

You can do this by using this code:

```
// This only works for GET requests, NOT for POST requests.
if ($request->has('version')) {
        return redirect()->to($request->fullUrlWithoutQuery('version'));
}

return $next($request);
```

Comment: This will not work if request is submitted by `POST` method

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze it can be any request

Comment: You can use the answer of @MalkhaziDartsmelidze as seen below.

Answer (score 0):

Just unset the query param.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if( $request->has('version') ){
        unset($request['version']);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: it is not working